# Getting a coder to perform triangulation

Tags: phd, qualitative-research

I am a PhD student currently working on a qualitative study. I have analysed my data and few reviewers have advised me to get another coder to code my data.

My data include video recording of about 40 hours. So analyzing those data would take minimum 80 hours in my experience.

Currently I am finding it difficult to find another person who can dedicate that time for coding my data. What are the common ways that PhD students follow to get coders to code their data?

Comment: Could you clarify what coder means in this context? For me a coder is either a software developer or a system to encode/decode data?

Comment: In the context of qualitative research, coding is a process to extract information  from qualitative data. Coder is the person who performs that. It is recommended to use multiple coders to analyse data to remove bias and to improve validity.

Answer (score 6):

Your reviewers are right! Having multiple coders is a best practice for this type of work. You could try to recruit:

Other PhD students (trades are best - I will code for you if you code for me).

Masters students in your same lab (may offer trade, co-authorship if they want to help with paper more generally, or payment)

Masters students you have taught (usually would offer payment)

Advanced undergrads who you train extensively (would likely offer payment)

To find these people, you could try to send an email on your department listserv. Additionally, many professional societies have listservs and you might be able to find other PhD students that way. You could also use social media to tap your network.